# my swift-executing functions are skipping over values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, properties, fetch-api

I'm working with an API in JS to create a movie info website and I'm calling an async function 3 times that fetches different endpoints based on the parameters I pass in.

I mapped across each object(value) in the 'result'(property of parsed response) array in order to set it's respective 'poster-path' property value as the respective image element's src attribute. it worked fine, but since i called the function thrice, anytime I try to target the object whose index is equal to that of my target image element, it seems to target only the objects gotten in the final function call.

```
    let result = res.json().result
    let imageID = e.target.data-id;
    let targetObject = result[imageID];
```

if I try to access targetObject's movie ID property for example, and the e.target is the image with an index of 0 in the first movie display(result of the first function call), rather than targetting the targetObject with an index of 0 in the same first movie display, it will target the object with an index of 0 in the third movie display.

Please how do I target the object with the same index as my e.target and in the 'same' display without it being overridden by the last. I'm very sorry if I didn't word this correctly, I'm still new to programming.